# sudo apt dist-upgrade trying to install packages that do not exist in third-party ppa

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I have installed parrotOS PPA in my ubuntu 20.04, so I can easily install and update hacking tools.

Then I am updating `/etc/apt/preferences.d/parrot-pinning`, in order to do the following:

- If a tool both exists in ubuntu ppa and parrotOS ppa, it will install from ubuntu (So I changed `Pin-Priority` of ubuntu to be higher than parrot)

Contents of `/etc/apt/preferences.d/parrot-pinning`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Parrot
Pin-Priority: 500

Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release o=Kali
Pin-Priority: 50

Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

##### My problem is

While doing `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, apt is trying to update tools in parrotOS PPA to a version that does not exist in the mirror.

Excerpt taken after running the command:

```
Deseja continuar? [S/n] S                #note the Y/n option to continue with upgrade
Err:1 https://mirrors.up.pt/parrot rolling/main amd64 codium amd64 1.60.0-1630974030
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:690:2200:1200::15 443]
Err:2 https://mirrors.up.pt/parrot rolling/non-free amd64 oracle-instantclient-basic amd64 19.6.0.0.0-0parrot1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:690:2200:1200::15 443]
Err:3 https://mirrors.up.pt/parrot rolling/main amd64 metasploit-framework amd64 6.1.2-0parrot1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:690:2200:1200::15 443]
```

**Following the url the file does not exist and the latest codium version is *codium_1.56.2-1620951495_amd64.deb*.**

Output of `ubuntu-security-status`:

```
2139 packages installed, of which:
1877 receive package updates with LTS until 4/2025
 247 could receive security updates with ESM Apps until 4/2030
  14 packages are from third parties
   1 package is no longer available for download

Packages from third parties are not provided by the official Ubuntu
archive, for example packages from Personal Package Archives in
Launchpad.
For more information on the packages, run 'ubuntu-security-status
--thirdparty'.

Packages that are not available for download may be left over from a
previous release of Ubuntu, may have been installed directly from a
.deb file, or are from a source which has been disabled.
For more information on the packages, run 'ubuntu-security-status
--unavailable'.

Enable Extended Security Maintenance (ESM Apps) to get 1 security
update (so far) and enable coverage of 247 packages.

This machine is not attached to an Ubuntu Advantage subscription.
See https://ubuntu.com/advantage
```

Output of `sudo apt update`: (translated text to english)

```
Atg:1 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Atg:2 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Atg:3 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Atg:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Atg:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Atg:6 https://repo.pritunl.com/stable/apt focal InRelease                      
Atg:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease           
Atg:8 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling InRelease        
Atg:9 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling-security InRelease
Reading package list...
building dependency tree...       
Reading state information...
36 packets can be upgraded. run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Comment: the file at https://mirrors.up.pt/parrot/dists/rolling/main/binary-amd64/Packages (67Mo) lists the 1.60 version, so the problem is not related to your pin preferences

Comment: But it doesn't exist at [https://mirrors.up.pt/parrot/pool/main/c/codium/](https://mirrors.up.pt/parrot/pool/main/c/codium/), where I assume it is trying to download it from. Does this mean the problem is the PPA and not me?

From the mirrors I saw, none has the version 1.60 in the folder I said.

Comment: it's not you, it looks like it's the mirror who's lagging: berkeley has the good deb http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/parrot/pool/main/c/codium/codium_1.60.0-1630974030_amd64.deb

Comment: Changing mirrors fixed the issue, create and answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a problem of your mirror, not of your pin settings: the file is listed in the [packages list](https://mirrors.up.pt/parrot/dists/rolling/main/binary-amd64/), and is indeed missing from the [repo](https://mirrors.up.pt/parrot/pool/main/c/codium/)

change your mirror